# Does Bootstrap 3.x need meyerweb reset?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Chrome user agent stylesheet is applying the following rule to an unordered list:

```
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

This can seen in the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/robinsm/4hem938o/1/

If I apply the meyerweb reset css, then harmony is restored and the Chrome user agent stylesheet is *overridden*: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

However, I thought this was unnecessary with Bootstrap and perhaps even advised against.

I'm concerned using the reset might have unforeseen implications elsewhere.

What is the ideal solution here?

Comment: Bootstrap already uses [normalize.css](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize) as a CSS reset

Comment: @MTCoster Thanks for comment. It does but it doesn't seem to reset the above rule in particular?  Which can be seen in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to suppress the initial padding by using Bootstrap's `inline-list` class:

```css
.event-categories>li {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.event-categories>li::after {
  padding-left: 8px;
  content: "/";
}

.event-categories li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}

.event-categories a {
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
            <ul class="event-categories list-inline">
                <li><a href="#">Triathlon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">25 - 50km</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">50 - 100km</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">10 - 15 miles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">15 - 50 miles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lake</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for taking the time to answer an old question.  I've added the list-inline class to the relevant areas and have removed the meyer reset.  It removed the padding as expected.  Thanks again.